# button is refreshing page instead of calling function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button that is being used to toggle a class on a div to open and close a side menu.

```
<div id="body-holder" [ngClass]="{'show-nav':isActive}">
    <div class="site-wrap">
    <button class="toggle-nav" (click)="flipper()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

In my component.ts file i have the following code.

```
isActive: boolean = true;

    flipper()
    {
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
```

however instead of toggling the class when I click the button the page gets reloaded instead and redirects me to my application homepage.

Comment: All else being equal, that code should not have that behaviour. (I'd expect otherwise if the button was in a form, but it isn't).

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add preventDefault to your click event in this way:

```
flipper(event: any)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
```

and in your html code:

```
<button class="toggle-nav" type="button" (click)="flipper($event)">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
</button>
```

Comment: but still redirects to homepage? can you show more your code?

Answer (score 0):

Set button type attribute to `type="button"`:

```
   <button type="button" class="toggle-nav" (click)="flipper()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button type to `type="button"` might also solve the problem

```
<button type="button"
```

It seems your button is inside a form and causes a submit.

Comment: my button is not inside any form

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. Clicking a button doesn't reload the page and Angular also doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Button inside division or form most of the times have default behavior of loading the page. For that reason, It's better to set type attribute of button as "buton".

```
<button type="button" class="toggle-nav" onclick="flipper()"> <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
```

I think there is mistake in function. You missed to mention "funtion" keyword before you define the function. I tried a sample fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdcmonks/28/)

```
<script>
isActive: boolean = true;

   function flipper()
    {
       alert("a");
    }
</script>
```